# How to get which file is requested to open using a mac application?

Tags: macos, applescript

I have created a mac application which can be open my file extensions.

But when I tested it, I dont get the path of the file requested to open using the application, instead I got the "psn_0_151589".

I checked it for itunes, textedit, xcode and other applications.

Below is my python app sample main code where i process path of the opened file

```
import sys
import os.path
print("File opened with this app :: ",sys.argv[1])
if(os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
  print("valid file :: { do something...}\n")
else:
  print("Invalid file path received :: { do nothing }\n")
```

OUTPUT :

```
File opened with this app :: psn_0_151589
Invalid file path received :: { do nothing }
```

Hope someone knows how to get the filepath which was opened using any application.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you posted your code it would be easier to understand your question.

Comment: updated above with the sample code and its output

Answer (score 2):

Mac OS X application bundles don't receive the files to be opened as command line arguments. As every application usually only has a single instance, this'd restrict opening further files. Instead, it's a message sent when the application is already running. The argument you receive is the process serial number. [More information here](http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-69397/t-207344.html).

---

You could alternatively wrap your Python script in an Automator application's *Run Shell Script* action (`#!/usr/bin/python` being the "shell"). When you select to pass input *as arguments*, they'll be made available in `argv`, see the sample code:

[image: Screenshot]